# How to make a stretchable div with respect to div inside it

Tags: html, css

How can i make a parent div (red) stretchable so that min number of chidren inside it can be one and maximum number can be 3 after which the fourth div sets vertically down automatically.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My css for inner div is

```
.inner_div {
min-height: 238px;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
border-right: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
border-top: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
border-left: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
float: left;
padding: 9px;
width: 200px;
background-color: white;
}
```

and css for parent (outer div) is

```
.outer_div {
    padding: 0 20px;
margin-top: 55px!important;
margin-bottom: 33px!important;
background: white;
border-left: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 611px;
min-width: 223px;
width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Let's Get Fluid!

There are a lot of answers here!

The following example works across all screen sizes / widths for up to 3 boxes across.

That `@media` is used to give and take borders away at each viewport width, one column up to three columns. It also re-sizes the outer div for each step, and changes the background colour, etc if wanted. Refer to the comments in the snippet for a basic explanation of what's going on.

**This example can consume as many or as few boxes as you want.** Open it full screen and resize to see the results.

**Update** - I have given the inners a dark green background and the outer is `display: inline-block` to resize with its contents.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* incorporate padding into width (.outer_div padding is excluded) */
}
.outer_div {
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 640px;
  min-width: 240px;
  /* 200 * 3 across + 40 .outer_div padding = 640 */
  padding: 20px;
  /* transition? yes! on re-size! */
  transition: background 1s;
  transition: max-width 0.05s;
}
.inner_div {
  min-height: 238px;
  /* BORDER ALL THE THINGS!!!*/
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  float: left;
  padding: 9px;
  /* padding is accounted for in the width thanks to border-box */
  width: 200px;
  background: #0a8f08;
}
/* Clear the floats at the very end */

.outer_div:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  clear: left;
}
/* 3 boxes across */

/*@media sizes increase and decrease dependant on inner box width and outer_div padding */

@media screen and (min-width: 756px) {
  .outer_div {
    background: #a3e9a4;
  }
  /* Remove all bottom borders */
  .inner_div {
    border-bottom: none
  }
  /* Remove every middle border  */
  .inner_div:nth-child(3n+2) {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
  }
  /* Last child gets a right border  */
  .inner_div:last-child {
    border-right: 1px dashed #000;
  }
  /* last three get a bottom border */
  .inner_div:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  }
}
/* 2 boxes across */

@media screen and (min-width: 573px) and (max-width: 755px) {
  .outer_div {
    max-width: 440px;
    background: #dcedc8;
  }
  /* Remove all bottom borders */
  .inner_div {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  /* Remove every second border */
  .inner_div:nth-child(2n) {
    border-left: none;
  }
  /* last two get a bottom border */
  .inner_div:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  }
}
/* 1 box across */

@media screen and (max-width: 572px) {
  .outer_div {
    max-width: 240px;
    background: #f0f4c3;
  }
  /* Remove all bottom borders */
  .inner_div {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  /* last one gets a border */
  .inner_div:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No didn't work, try delete an inner element, the outer div will still remain static !!

Comment: annnnd now I know what you meant. It will now resize when there are only 1 or 2 divs. I had to make the outer `display: inline-block`. Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably add some pixels to you outer_div's max-width, otherwise 3 inner_divs just don't fit:

```
max-width: 660px;
```

And then clear every third inner_div:

```
.inner_div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

---

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bknu1djh/).

Answer (score 1):

**Just change your outer div css with this**

```
 .outer_div {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-top: 55px!important;
    margin-bottom: 33px!important;
    background: white;
    border-left: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 223px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code change parameter as your needs proportionally.

`display:inline-block;` can do the tricks

```
.outer_div{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  overflow:auto;
}
.inner_div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:black;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo class.

To make the parent div stretchable, add a `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

```
.outer_div {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-top: 55px!important;
    margin-bottom: 33px!important;
    background: white;
    border-left: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;

    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
}
.inner_div {
    min-height: 238px;
    border: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
    float: left;
    padding: 9px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}
.inner_div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

You can see the result in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt1rmcd3/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 1):

In inner-div class add this line

`display:inline-block;`

and outer-div must be like this

`.outer_div {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-top: 55px!important;
    margin-bottom: 33px!important;
    background: white;
    border-left: 1px dashed #e7e7e7;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 669px;
    min-width: 223px;
   }`

You can always change max-width to get more free space for fourth block or remove third block!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this kind of thing.

There would be a lot of possibilities/combinations, and would also be very easy to edit if required.

The likes of:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px; /* Or whatever */
}

.child {
  width: 100px;  /* Or whatever */
  height: 100px; /* Or whatever */
  margin: auto;  /* Magic! */
}
```

Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/LklCv) of just one possibility.

**Browser support:**

[See here](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)